# What is the meaning of the time under the result of MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, time, execute

Is this the time when the machine only executes the query or it includes the time machine displays the query?

I ask this question because I access to the remote MySQL server from my computer, and the result I receive is ~ 5000 records in ~15s. But I do the same thing right in this remote MySQL server by the same user, I receive 5000 records in ~0.02s.

Why are the two timings different?

Comment: It most likely is: time it takes to run the query + time it takes to transfer and display it to the client. So it is elapsed time on the client, not execution time on the server. The fact that it takes 15 seconds remotely, and 0.02s locally pretty much shows this is the case :)

Comment: I don't think it includes the time it displays. Because the way they measure this time is the same for remote and local. At local, it takes only 0.02s, too short!!! But I have to wait about ~3-4s to view all the records. Anyone can give me the source show the way they measure the execution time? :(

Comment: Where are you seeing this time? In the MySQL console?

Answer (score 1):

If all you really want to do is measure server execution time then maybe you'd like to take  a look at
 [`SHOW PROFILES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html).

Example:

```
mysql> set profiling = 1;

mysql> select count(*) from xyz;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10697 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> show profiles;
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                          |
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.01904200 | select count(*) from xyz       |
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it takes a bit more time is that

- You execute queries remotely
- You execute queries locally

The network transfer time also needs to be taken in when queries run through the network. You can checkout this post to understand [network latency](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/01/how-network-can-impact-mysql-operations/) better.

Answer (score 0):

It means the time the DBMS needed to execute the query (according to its query plan).